# Remove Extra Expose Messages From X11 Queue

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I have a program that has a thread that generates `Expose` messages using `XSendEvent`.  A second thread receives the `Expose` messages along with other messages (mainly input handling).  The problem is that the sending thread sends the `Expose` messages at a constant rate (~60Hz) but the receiving thread may be rendering slower than that.  The X11 queue will get bogged down with extra `Expose` messages, and any input handling messages will start fall way behind all those extra `Expose` messages.

In Windows, this is not a problem because Windows will automatically coalesce all WM_PAINT messages into a single message.  Is there any way to do this in X11, or some other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can very easily coalesce any kind of event yourself with `XCheckTypedEvent()` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem as follows:

Block the rendering thread using `XPeekEvent`.

When an event comes in, read all events into a new queue data structure using a combination of `XPending` and `XNextEvent`, but only copy the first expose message.

Then run the event processing loop over the new queue data structure.

This fixed the problem for me, but I think a solution that uses `XCheckTypedEvent` (per n.m.'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678322/1991678)) is probably  more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

A few of thing you can do:

- If you are doing complete redraw for each event, only action events with a count of 0, count > 1 is the redraw of a particular rectange
- If you generate expose events for part of the window, this will reduce the amount of work each expose event does
- The constant rate, means you could just process every nth event or keep a time since the last event and ignore events received within a given time